# Angular cascade selects based on ReST response

Tags: angularjs, rest

I want to have multiple select statements where the options of this select are filled based on a ReST Call from data of the previous select. For example:
First select would identify a letter from a to z:
Second select would identify the artists in the DB with the first selects letter.
Third select would identify the songs in the DB with that artist.

I have looked at a bunch of angular examples but none seem to have that kind of dynamicity. Is there an example somewhere that I can use as a model?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question I replied some weeks ago, it may help you to see how to show the select options depending on the previous select option selected.

[Angular select based on previous select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442061/angularjs-ng-options-with-nested-json-based-on-previous-select-option/37442242#37442242)

Comment: This still bases everything on pre-existing data. I need to load data after the first select has been chosen.

Comment: Then instead of loading the pre existing data ask the data to your backend when your select changes (you can add an ng-change="function()" to the select tag and when the value changes, the function is called. And inside the function do the backend call asking for the data that you want to display.